# React native auto import not suggesting react-native views

Tags: javascript, react-native, visual-studio-code, auto-import

I have a problem with auto importing react native views like View,Button,TextInput etc...
when i want to use auto import i have other modules suggestions but nothing from the react-native itself
[image]

For example i want to import {view} from 'react-native; but in dropdown i cant find it. I know I had it before but somehow it's gone.

I also created jsconfig.json like the code below but it did not work

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was somehow related to VSCode workspace, I've created new workspace and moved the project folder again into VSCode and the problem is solved now.